# RTK Query customize and ignore specific query params used to cache requests

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have an api i do not control

I want to only use some of the query params in the RTK document store to cache requests.

For example when calling the generated hook

```
const {data, error, isLoading} = useReqQuery({ 
  param1: val1, 
  param2: val2, 
  param3: val3, 
  param4: val4
})
```

I want to only cache requests when param1 and param2 are different and not param3 or param4.

I have looked at the docs and found cache lifecycle functions but not seeing if there are ways to ignore specific query params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can customize how requests are cached using the [serializeQueryArgs option in createApi](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#serializequeryargs)

```js
// apiSlice.ts
getEntities: builder.query({
    query: ({ param1, param2, param3, param4 }) => ({
      url: entityEndpoint,
      method: 'POST',
    }),
    serializeQueryArgs: ({ queryArgs }) => {
      const { param1, param2 } = queryArgs;
      // omits `param3`, and `param4` from the cache key
      return { param1, param2 }; 
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you can come is to use skip to not fetch again when your parameters you want to ignore are the same as some stored value. However, if they're not relevant to what is considered to be the current value of the api call, consider whether you can change the api signature where it doesn't expect them or populate them with dummy values from inside the endpoint definition.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no way to do this.
`serializeQueryArgs` from @reduxjs/toolkit@~1.9.7 does not prevents multiple requests when `useQuery` hook calls with different params and `serializeQueryArgs` returns only unchanging params.

Comment: It is possible and I have already provided an answer. Sorry if the question confused you, it was written before I had the correct rtk query vocabulary.
You are asking a different question i would suggest a separate post for your scenario.